# boost converter minimum input current

Tags: analog, dc-dc-converter, buck-boost

i have 15V to 30V 30A boost converter, what is the minimum input current should i supply to get 30A at ouput? (my device consume about 30A) does it 30A?

Comment: Welcome to EESE.  Please provide more details describing your setup, including part numbers and links to relevant datasheets.  Including a schematic of your circuit is often the best way to convey your intentions, and obtain an answer to your questions.

Comment: keep in mind that for a boost, that current rating is for the input, so you can't get 30A at the output with it.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming a boost converter power efficiency of about 85%, it needs to take about 1060 watts from the 15 volt supply in order to deliver 30 volts at 30 amps to the load. That means the 15 volt supply will need to deliver about 71 amps.